# How to find the curve equation by the points given in the Mathematica program

Tags: interpolation

Points

```
{5.10683, 1.66843}, {5.12076, 1.67006}, {5.13543, 1.67133}, {5.15058, 1.67241}, {5.1661, 1.67338}, {5.18191, 1.67428}, {5.19796, 1.67516}, {5.21423, 1.67602}, {5.2307, 1.67688}, {5.24738, 1.67773}, {5.26425, 1.67858}, {5.28133, 1.67944}, {5.29859, 1.6803}, {5.31606, 1.68117}, {5.33372, 1.68204}, {5.35159, 1.68292}, {5.36965, 1.6838}, {5.38792, 1.68468}, {5.40638, 1.68557}, {5.42506, 1.68647}, {5.44394, 1.68737}, {5.46302, 1.68827}, {5.48231, 1.68918}, {5.50182, 1.6901}, {5.52153, 
1.69102}, {5.54146, 1.69194}, {5.5616, 1.69287}, {5.58195, 1.6938}, {5.60252, 1.69473}, {5.62331, 1.69567}, {5.64431, 1.69662}, {5.66553, 1.69757}, {5.68698, 1.69852}, {5.70865, 1.69948}, 
{5.73053, 1.70044}
```

are given.
Find the equation of the function $ f (x) $ that passes through these points.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=2$$

Comment: You should arrange your data points in groups of two: `Partition[data, 2]`

Comment: There are infinite many functions through these points. You must specify some form.

Comment: Note that this site is for Q&A about **Mathematica** not **Wolfram|Alpha** (I am guessing that is what you meant by "tungsten alpha")

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it pertains to Wolfram | Alpha and is therefore out of scope for MSE.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approximation might be

```
xy = {{5.10683, 1.66843}, {5.12076, 1.67006}, {5.13543, 1.67133}, {5.15058, 1.67241}, {5.1661, 1.67338}, {5.18191,1.67428}, {5.19796, 1.67516}, {5.21423, 1.67602}, {5.2307, 1.67688}, {5.24738, 1.67773}, {5.26425, 1.67858}, {5.28133, 1.67944}, {5.29859, 1.6803}, {5.31606, 1.68117}, {5.33372, 1.68204}, {5.35159, 1.68292}, {5.36965, 1.6838}, {5.38792, 1.68468}, {5.40638, 1.68557}, {5.42506, 1.68647}, {5.44394, 1.68737}, {5.46302, 1.68827}, {5.48231, 1.68918}, {5.50182, 1.6901}, {5.52153, 1.69102}, {5.54146, 1.69194}, {5.5616,1.69287}, {5.58195, 1.6938}, {5.60252, 1.69473}, {5.62331,1.69567}, {5.64431, 1.69662}, {5.66553, 1.69757}, {5.68698,1.69852}, {5.70865, 1.69948}, {5.73053, 1.70044}}

nml = NonlinearModelFit[xy, (a + 2 x )/(b + x ), {a, b}, x]
```